# In a Form Model Binding form, how do I access the variable without using a helper?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am building a form using Form Model Binding via the Laravel Collective HTML package. The documentation (https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#form-model-binding) boasts how the model's value is conveniently available with the value being set in the priority order of:

- Session Flash Data (Old Input)
- Explicitly Passed Value
- Model Attribute Data

This is super useful because if a user has changed multiple fields, but 1 of them fails validation, you don't want all the other fields being reset to original value when they get thrown back to the form page with a helpful Message Bag of errors to give them a chance to correct their invalid input.

It's all very well using the `Form::label`, `Form::text` and `Form::select` helpers to leverage this lovely feature but what if you just want to access that convenient variable directly to do something a bit left-field?

Here's what I have tried...

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('route' => array('user.update', $user->id))) }}

    {{ Form::label('first_name', 'First Name:', array('class' => 'address')) }}
    {{ Form::text('first_name') }}

    {{ Form::value('first_name') }}      <-- No
    {{ Form::session('first_name') }}    <-- Nope
    {{ Form::input('first_name') }}      <-- Still no
    {{ Form::attribute('first_name') }}  <-- Absolutely not

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Help me, what is the method I am looking for?

The documentation hints at the ability to get the thing I want here: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#custom-macros where it says it's "easy" to define your own custom Form class helpers called "macros" but it doesn't actually tell you where you would write the code for this or where in the code you can look if you want to poke around and learn more about the FormBuilder class?

Comment: Decide what version of Laravel you are writing about. Form package is not any more in Laravel 5 (it's in separate Laravel Collective), and you tagged this as Laravel 5 but you give links to Laravel 4.2 documentation

Comment: And why you write about Taylor and documentation? As far as I know Taylor doesn't manage Laravel collective (last commits in 2015) so he doesn't have anything in common with documentation of Laravel Collective.

Comment: Woah woah woah calm down! Your first comment will shed light on why I was writing about Taylor: I was mistakenly referencing 4.2 documentation. That documentation is credited to Taylor isn't it. I made 1 mistake and during the time it took me to edit the post you've gone and got yourself all puffed up and angry. Give me time to improve the question.

Comment: Why do you thin I'm angry? It seems you created Q&A and you put quite incorrect data into question that were rather misleading than helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method for doing this is `Form::getValueAttribute('first_name')` and the location for poking around to learn more is `/vendor/laravelcollective/html/src/FormBuilder.php`